# Pandas: Outer Join on Non-Unique Index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a MultiIndex as follows:

```
>>> dfNew.head()
                 status  shopping        TUFNWGTP
state date                                       
6     2003-01-03    emp         0  8155462.672158
      2003-01-03    emp         0  8155462.672158
      2003-01-03    emp         0  8155462.672158
      2003-01-04    emp         0  1735322.527819
      2003-01-04    emp         0  1735322.527819
```

You can't see it here, but `status` can take three values: `emp`, `unemp`, `NaN`. This is data at the state-date level. I would like to join new state-date data, which is at a different frequency, and then aggregate/group over time.

```
>>> test['foo'].head()
state  date      
1      2004-01-01     1985886
2      2004-01-01      301172
4      2004-01-01     2614525
5      2004-01-01     1180409
6      2004-01-01    16098932
```

## Join without how=inner

Here is what I do:

```
dfNew = dfNew.join(test['foo'], method)
dfNew.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
doWhat = {'shopping' : np.sum, 'TUFNWGTP': np.sum, 'foo' : np.mean}
aggASS = dfNew.groupby(['state', pd.TimeGrouper("2AS", label='left'), 'status']).agg(doWhat)
```

This *should*:

- join `foo` from the other database for every date-time combination, and create 2-year based values.

But here's what I get:

```
>>> aggASS.head()
                                    foo      shopping      TUFNWGTP
state date       status                                            
1     2003-01-01 emp     2007116.941176  2.910812e+12  4.500711e+09
                 unemp              NaN  7.836728e+11  5.590089e+08
      2005-01-01 emp     2062059.100000  2.026485e+12  4.440291e+09
                 unemp   2078869.000000  7.543956e+10  2.638597e+08
```

Observe how `foo` has a value for `status=emp`, but not a value for `status=unemp`, for the same `state` and `date`.

## Join with how=inner

`join` does `how=inner` on default, so this seems to be the issue. However, if I

```
>>> dfNew = dfNew.join(test['foo'], how='outer')
NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented
```

Yes, `state`-`date` is not unique here. But as far as I can understand it, what I want still *makes sense* (doesn't it?). What would be an efficient work around here?

## Suggested Solution: Append as Column

One suggested solution was to append them as a column instead:

Using `sort level` to align the data frames:

```
>>> dfNew.head()
                 status  shopping        TUFNWGTP
state date                                       
1     2003-01-01    emp         0  3227364.873298
      2003-01-01    NaN         0  6841114.725821
      2003-01-01    NaN         0  6841114.725821
      2003-01-01    NaN         0  6841114.725821
      2003-01-01    NaN         0  6841114.725821
>>> test['foo'].head()
state  date      
1      2004-01-01    1985886
       2004-02-01    1990082
       2004-03-01    1999936
       2004-04-01    2009556
       2004-05-01    2009573
```

we then add the second time series as a column `dfNew.append(test['foo'])`. I was suggested `ignore_index=True`, but I think that because index labels are correct, we don't need that.

However, this crashes my instance of Python. Here's the size of the data frames:

```
>>> len(test['foo'])
6864
>>> len(dfNew)
404394
```

- Some paste of `dfNew`: http://pastebin.com/rJjh6ZSc
- Some paste of `test`: http://pastebin.com/Er70XD9y

Comment: I think I may have a solution. A few questions -- what is the method in the join statement? Does the joining table have a status value like the first table -- I see test['emp'] is that like status in the first table? Am I correct in assuming there are not matching state-date combinations since you're trying to get a sum and mean over time?

Comment: @kennes913 no it doesn't. What you observed was a left-over typo. `test` originally had a column also called 'emp', which referred to something else. For clearness of the question, I renamed it here to `foo` - you found the one spot I forgot to change. There are no matching state-date combinations in `test`, there is just a time series `foo`. For this time series, I need to find means over groups of time. I need to join before aggregation because they have different frequencies: `dfNew` starts in `2003`, `test` starts in `2004`, but I want to match these via the mean values of `test['foo']`.

Comment: did the below solution work?

Comment: @kennes913 my `yourtimeseries` does not contain `state` - but I see the approach and am also thinking of a way to make `append` work

Comment: If you do your append and then classify your buckets of time in another column, you'll be able to easily group and calculate on those buckets.

Comment: did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @kennes913 No. I tried to add them as a column in your spirit, but apparently when the index shapes are not the same, `append` is quite inefficient, and my Python instance crashes - see update.

Comment: Okay, can you send me a small sample of both data?

Comment: @kennes913 I have linked short paste bins for `state=1,2` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the steps I took. Hopefully, this can lead you down a road to generating a solution.

I recreated the multi-index data frame and the time series you provided:

```
In [118]: newdf
Out[118]: 
                      0           1                2
state date                                          
1     2003-01-01    emp           0   3227364.873298
      2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
      2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
      2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
      2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
      2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
      2003-01-02    NaN           0   5834127.649776
      2003-01-02    NaN           0   5834127.649776
      2003-01-04    emp  2100942000   1506051.861585
      2003-01-04    emp  2100942000   1506051.861585
      2003-01-04    emp  5412841000   1204191.605090
      2003-01-04    emp  5412841000   1204191.605090
      2003-01-04    emp  5412841000   1204191.605090
      2003-01-05    NaN           0   1765953.711812
      2003-01-05    NaN           0   1765953.711812
      2003-01-05    emp           0   1434858.212964
      2003-01-05    emp           0   1434858.212964
      2003-01-05    emp           0   1434858.212964
      2003-01-05    emp           0   1811326.258197
      2003-01-05    emp           0   1811326.258197
      2003-01-05    NaN           0   1908483.149300
      2003-01-05    NaN           0   1908483.149300
      2003-01-06    NaN  1298934000   4190110.086256
      2003-01-07    NaN           0   6241047.457860
      2003-01-07    NaN           0   6241047.457860
      2003-01-07    NaN           0   6241047.457860
      2003-01-07    NaN           0   6241047.457860
      2003-01-08    emp   715231400   4614396.137509
      2003-01-08    emp   715231400   4614396.137509
      2003-01-08    emp   715231400   4614396.137509
2     2013-08-01    emp           0  10571046.129186
      2013-08-01    emp           0  10571046.129186
      2013-08-01    emp           0  10571046.129186
      2013-08-01    emp           0  10571046.129186
      2013-08-27    NaN  6804297000   3376822.385266
      2013-08-27    NaN  6804297000   3376822.385266
      2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
      2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
      2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
      2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
      2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
      2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
      2013-10-18    emp           0  14402621.620998
      2013-10-18    emp           0  14402621.620998
      2013-11-02  unemp           0   7778017.482167
      2013-11-02  unemp           0   7778017.482167
      2013-11-02  unemp           0   7778017.482167
      2013-11-09    NaN           0   2164565.290873
      2013-11-09    NaN           0   2164565.290873
      2013-11-10    emp   527859500   1759531.507169
      2013-11-10    emp   527859500   1759531.507169
      2013-11-24    emp           0   3050339.003118
      2013-11-24    emp           0   3050339.003118
      2013-11-24    emp           0   3050339.003118
      2013-11-29    NaN           0  11224606.711441
      2013-11-29    NaN           0  11224606.711441
      2013-12-12    emp           0  13804339.863606
      2013-12-12    emp           0  13804339.863606
      2013-12-12    emp           0  13804339.863606
      2013-12-12    emp           0  13804339.863606

In [120]: newfoo
Out[120]: 
                      foo
state date               
1     2004-01-01  1985886
      2004-02-01  1990082
      2004-03-01  1999936
      2004-04-01  2009556
      2004-05-01  2009573
      2004-06-01  2013057
      2004-07-01  2019963
      2004-08-01  2015320
      2004-09-01  2015103
      2004-10-01  2035705
      2004-11-01  2043152
      2004-12-01  2041339
      2005-01-01  2011219
      2005-02-01  2014928
      2005-03-01  2028597
2     2013-10-01   340483
      2013-11-01   338445
      2013-12-01   336903
      2014-01-01   334565
      2014-02-01   334667
      2014-03-01   335922
      2014-04-01   337188
      2014-05-01   343958
      2014-06-01   349122
      2014-07-01   354911
      2014-08-01   350833
      2014-09-01   344849
      2014-10-01   341434
      2014-11-01   339866
      2014-12-01   339203
```

I flattened the data frame and time series:

```
   In [147]: flattenednewdf
Out[147]: 
    state       date status    shopping         TUFNWGTP
0       1 2003-01-01    emp           0   3227364.873298
1       1 2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
2       1 2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
3       1 2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
4       1 2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
5       1 2003-01-01    NaN           0   6841114.725821
6       1 2003-01-02    NaN           0   5834127.649776
7       1 2003-01-02    NaN           0   5834127.649776
8       1 2003-01-04    emp  2100942000   1506051.861585
9       1 2003-01-04    emp  2100942000   1506051.861585
10      1 2003-01-04    emp  5412841000   1204191.605090
11      1 2003-01-04    emp  5412841000   1204191.605090
12      1 2003-01-04    emp  5412841000   1204191.605090
13      1 2003-01-05    NaN           0   1765953.711812
14      1 2003-01-05    NaN           0   1765953.711812
15      1 2003-01-05    emp           0   1434858.212964
16      1 2003-01-05    emp           0   1434858.212964
17      1 2003-01-05    emp           0   1434858.212964
18      1 2003-01-05    emp           0   1811326.258197
19      1 2003-01-05    emp           0   1811326.258197
20      1 2003-01-05    NaN           0   1908483.149300
21      1 2003-01-05    NaN           0   1908483.149300
22      1 2003-01-06    NaN  1298934000   4190110.086256
23      1 2003-01-07    NaN           0   6241047.457860
24      1 2003-01-07    NaN           0   6241047.457860
25      1 2003-01-07    NaN           0   6241047.457860
26      1 2003-01-07    NaN           0   6241047.457860
27      1 2003-01-08    emp   715231400   4614396.137509
28      1 2003-01-08    emp   715231400   4614396.137509
29      1 2003-01-08    emp   715231400   4614396.137509
30      2 2013-08-01    emp           0  10571046.129186
31      2 2013-08-01    emp           0  10571046.129186
32      2 2013-08-01    emp           0  10571046.129186
33      2 2013-08-01    emp           0  10571046.129186
34      2 2013-08-27    NaN  6804297000   3376822.385266
35      2 2013-08-27    NaN  6804297000   3376822.385266
36      2 2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
37      2 2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
38      2 2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
39      2 2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
40      2 2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
41      2 2013-09-28    NaN           0   4645591.067481
42      2 2013-10-18    emp           0  14402621.620998
43      2 2013-10-18    emp           0  14402621.620998
44      2 2013-11-02  unemp           0   7778017.482167
45      2 2013-11-02  unemp           0   7778017.482167
46      2 2013-11-02  unemp           0   7778017.482167
47      2 2013-11-09    NaN           0   2164565.290873
48      2 2013-11-09    NaN           0   2164565.290873
49      2 2013-11-10    emp   527859500   1759531.507169
50      2 2013-11-10    emp   527859500   1759531.507169
51      2 2013-11-24    emp           0   3050339.003118
52      2 2013-11-24    emp           0   3050339.003118
53      2 2013-11-24    emp           0   3050339.003118
54      2 2013-11-29    NaN           0  11224606.711441
55      2 2013-11-29    NaN           0  11224606.711441
56      2 2013-12-12    emp           0  13804339.863606
57      2 2013-12-12    emp           0  13804339.863606
58      2 2013-12-12    emp           0  13804339.863606
59      2 2013-12-12    emp           0  13804339.863606


In [143]: flattenedfoo
Out[143]: 
    state       date      foo
0       1 2004-01-01  1985886
1       1 2004-02-01  1990082
2       1 2004-03-01  1999936
3       1 2004-04-01  2009556
4       1 2004-05-01  2009573
5       1 2004-06-01  2013057
6       1 2004-07-01  2019963
7       1 2004-08-01  2015320
8       1 2004-09-01  2015103
9       1 2004-10-01  2035705
10      1 2004-11-01  2043152
11      1 2004-12-01  2041339
12      1 2005-01-01  2011219
13      1 2005-02-01  2014928
14      1 2005-03-01  2028597
15      2 2013-10-01   340483
16      2 2013-11-01   338445
17      2 2013-12-01   336903
18      2 2014-01-01   334565
19      2 2014-02-01   334667
20      2 2014-03-01   335922
21      2 2014-04-01   337188
22      2 2014-05-01   343958
23      2 2014-06-01   349122
24      2 2014-07-01   354911
25      2 2014-08-01   350833
26      2 2014-09-01   344849
27      2 2014-10-01   341434
28      2 2014-11-01   339866
29      2 2014-12-01   339203
```

I appended the time series to the data frame. I left the row and column count at the bottom so you can verify that this is the right data frame size given the examples you provided:

```
In [149]: final_df
Out[149]: 
          TUFNWGTP       date      foo    shopping  state status
0   3227364.873298 2003-01-01      NaN           0      1    emp
1   6841114.725821 2003-01-01      NaN           0      1    NaN
2   6841114.725821 2003-01-01      NaN           0      1    NaN
3   6841114.725821 2003-01-01      NaN           0      1    NaN
4   6841114.725821 2003-01-01      NaN           0      1    NaN
5   6841114.725821 2003-01-01      NaN           0      1    NaN
6   5834127.649776 2003-01-02      NaN           0      1    NaN
7   5834127.649776 2003-01-02      NaN           0      1    NaN
8   1506051.861585 2003-01-04      NaN  2100942000      1    emp
9   1506051.861585 2003-01-04      NaN  2100942000      1    emp
10  1204191.605090 2003-01-04      NaN  5412841000      1    emp
11  1204191.605090 2003-01-04      NaN  5412841000      1    emp
12  1204191.605090 2003-01-04      NaN  5412841000      1    emp
13  1765953.711812 2003-01-05      NaN           0      1    NaN
14  1765953.711812 2003-01-05      NaN           0      1    NaN
15  1434858.212964 2003-01-05      NaN           0      1    emp
16  1434858.212964 2003-01-05      NaN           0      1    emp
17  1434858.212964 2003-01-05      NaN           0      1    emp
18  1811326.258197 2003-01-05      NaN           0      1    emp
19  1811326.258197 2003-01-05      NaN           0      1    emp
20  1908483.149300 2003-01-05      NaN           0      1    NaN
21  1908483.149300 2003-01-05      NaN           0      1    NaN
22  4190110.086256 2003-01-06      NaN  1298934000      1    NaN
23  6241047.457860 2003-01-07      NaN           0      1    NaN
24  6241047.457860 2003-01-07      NaN           0      1    NaN
25  6241047.457860 2003-01-07      NaN           0      1    NaN
26  6241047.457860 2003-01-07      NaN           0      1    NaN
27  4614396.137509 2003-01-08      NaN   715231400      1    emp
28  4614396.137509 2003-01-08      NaN   715231400      1    emp
29  4614396.137509 2003-01-08      NaN   715231400      1    emp
..             ...        ...      ...         ...    ...    ...
0              NaN 2004-01-01  1985886         NaN      1    NaN
1              NaN 2004-02-01  1990082         NaN      1    NaN
2              NaN 2004-03-01  1999936         NaN      1    NaN
3              NaN 2004-04-01  2009556         NaN      1    NaN
4              NaN 2004-05-01  2009573         NaN      1    NaN
5              NaN 2004-06-01  2013057         NaN      1    NaN
6              NaN 2004-07-01  2019963         NaN      1    NaN
7              NaN 2004-08-01  2015320         NaN      1    NaN
8              NaN 2004-09-01  2015103         NaN      1    NaN
9              NaN 2004-10-01  2035705         NaN      1    NaN
10             NaN 2004-11-01  2043152         NaN      1    NaN
11             NaN 2004-12-01  2041339         NaN      1    NaN
12             NaN 2005-01-01  2011219         NaN      1    NaN
13             NaN 2005-02-01  2014928         NaN      1    NaN
14             NaN 2005-03-01  2028597         NaN      1    NaN
15             NaN 2013-10-01   340483         NaN      2    NaN
16             NaN 2013-11-01   338445         NaN      2    NaN
17             NaN 2013-12-01   336903         NaN      2    NaN
18             NaN 2014-01-01   334565         NaN      2    NaN
19             NaN 2014-02-01   334667         NaN      2    NaN
20             NaN 2014-03-01   335922         NaN      2    NaN
21             NaN 2014-04-01   337188         NaN      2    NaN
22             NaN 2014-05-01   343958         NaN      2    NaN
23             NaN 2014-06-01   349122         NaN      2    NaN
24             NaN 2014-07-01   354911         NaN      2    NaN
25             NaN 2014-08-01   350833         NaN      2    NaN
26             NaN 2014-09-01   344849         NaN      2    NaN
27             NaN 2014-10-01   341434         NaN      2    NaN
28             NaN 2014-11-01   339866         NaN      2    NaN
29             NaN 2014-12-01   339203         NaN      2    NaN

[90 rows x 6 columns]
```

Building time bins is new to me, but to use the method you provided, I had to set the index back to the date column. I created a new data frame because a lot of this process was experimental and I didn't want to have to rebuild old data frames:

```
final_df_2 = final_df.set_index(['date'])
```

From this point you should be able to do any calculations you want. I ran some below based on your code, but the problem is that we are grouping very selectively, so the results look very strange:

```
In [187]: doWhat = {'shopping' : np.sum, 'TUFNWGTP': np.sum, 'foo' : np.mean}

In [188]: aggASS = final_df_2.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("2AS", label='left')]).agg(doWhat)
In [189]: aggASS
Out[189]: 
                       foo     shopping      TUFNWGTP
date                                                 
2003-01-01  2014889.333333  23885035200  1.139995e+08
2005-01-01  2018248.000000          NaN           NaN
2013-01-01   341489.933333  14664313000  2.237165e+08

In [190]: aggASS = final_df_2.groupby(['state', pd.TimeGrouper("2AS", label='left'), 'status']).agg(doWhat)

In [191]: aggASS
Out[191]: 
                         foo     shopping      TUFNWGTP
state date       status                                
1     2003-01-01 emp     NaN  22586101200  3.162246e+07
2     2013-01-01 emp     NaN   1055719000  1.389769e+08
                 unemp   NaN            0  2.333405e+07
```

I read another post on bucketing using the [cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.cut.html?highlight=cut#pandas.cut) method. You can read it here -- [Grouping data by value ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349389/python-2-7-pandas-grouping-data-by-value-ranges). I am thinking you could build the 2 year buckets using datetime object manipulation.

Comment: Could you show the exact code you used to `append` - to create your `final_df`? My use of `append` crashed Python on the whole dataset.

Comment: @FooBar `final_df = flattenednewdf.append(flattenedfoo)` , did you remove the multi-index?

Answer (score 1):

This is the relevant part of @kennes913 's answer, just for overview of future visitors:

```
# flatten the data frames. For overview, just select one column each
df1flat = df.reset_index()[['state', 'date', 'TUFNWGTP']]
df2flat = df_emp.reset_index()[['state', 'date', 'foo']]
# the "merge"
X = df1flat.append(df2flat)
# now, recover the original data frames:
test1 = X.loc[np.isnan(X.foo) == False, ['state', 'date', 'foo']]
# fix dtype which was lost in the merge
test1['state'] = test1['state'].astype(int)

test2 = X.loc[np.isnan(X.TUCASEID) == False, ['state', 'date', 'TUFNWGTP']]
# check if nothing was lost:
print assert_frame_equal(bar, test1) # output: None
print assert_frame_equal(foo, test2) # output: None
```